# What is the parametric equation of a rotated Ellipse (given the angle of rotation)

Tags: rotations, parametric, elliptic-equations

The Formula of a ROTATED Ellipse is:

$$\dfrac {((X-C_x)\cos(\theta)+(Y-C_y)\sin(\theta))^2}{(R_x)^2}+\dfrac{((X-C_x) \sin(\theta)-(Y-C_y) \cos(\theta))^2}{(R_y)^2}=1$$

There:
- $(C_x, C_y)$ is the center of the Ellipse.
- $R_x$ is the Major-Radius, and $R_y$ is the Minor-Radius.
- $\theta$ is the angle of the Ellipse rotation.

What is the parametric equation of the Ellipse - equations of X and Y - given the Radiuses, Center, Angle to the Point ($\alpha$), and Angle of Ellipses rotation ($\theta$)??

See the graph of the rotated ellipse at: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fu0ko0hali

Comment: Maybe of interest https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/426150/what-is-the-general-equation-of-the-ellipse-that-is-not-in-the-origin-and-rotate and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941490/whats-the-parametric-equation-for-the-general-form-of-an-ellipse-rotated-by-any

Comment: Another one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4467121/solutions-for-y-for-a-rotated-ellipse

Comment: I saw both of these answers but they answer the question what is the generic form of the Ellipse formula. I already know the generic form of the Ellipse formula, but I can't find a way to isolate X and Y

Comment: Have you seen this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937259/whats-the-parametric-equation-for-the-general-form-of-an-ellipse-rotated-by-any ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Step 1 - The parametric equation of an ellipse

The parametric formula of an ellipse centered at $(0, 0)$, with the major axis parallel to the $x$-axis and minor axis parallel to the $y$-axis:

$$
x(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \\
y(\alpha) = R_y \sin(\alpha)
$$

where:

- $R_x$ is the major radius
- $R_y$ is the minor radius.

### Step 2 - Rotate the equation

The rotation is given by the mapping:
$$
x(\theta) = \cos(\theta) x - \sin(\theta) y\\
y(\theta) = \sin(\theta) x + \cos(\theta) y
$$
where:

- $\theta$ is the rotation angle.

Once we put the ellipse equation in the rotation equation we get:
$$
x(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \cos(\theta) - R_y \sin(\alpha) \sin(\theta) \\
y(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + R_y \sin(\alpha) \cos(\theta)
$$

### Step 3 - Shift the equation from the center at $(0, 0)$

To shift any equation from the center we add $C_x$ to the $x$ equation and $C_y$ to the $y$ equation.
Therefore the equation of a rotated ellipse is:
$$
x(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \cos(\theta) - R_y \sin(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + C_x \\
y(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + R_y \sin(\alpha) \cos(\theta) + C_y
$$

where:

- $C_x$ is the $x$-coordinate of the center
- $C_y$ is the $y$-coordinate of the center
- $R_x$ is the major radius
- $R_y$ is the minor radius
- $\alpha$ is  the parameter, which ranges from $0$ to $2 \pi$ radians
- $\theta$ is the ellipse rotation angle.