# How to find parameter for intersection of ellipse with vertical or horizontal line?

Tags: parametric, elliptic-equations

So I've got parametric ellipse equasion like in this post: [What is the parametric equation of a rotated Ellipse (given the angle of rotation)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645689/what-is-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-ellipse-given-the-angle-of-rotatio#new-answer?newreg=5c0210ecc9424f74a347499bcb7841d6)

$$x(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \cos(\theta) - R_y \sin(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + C_x \\
y(\alpha) = R_x \cos(\alpha) \sin(\theta) + R_y \sin(\alpha) \cos(\theta) + C_y$$

My question is how to find all $\alpha$ values for which ellipse intersects given vertical or horizontal line, e.g. $x=1$ or $y=2$.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’ve got an equation of the form $A\cos\alpha+B\sin\alpha = C$, so you could solve it directly, getting an unpleasant-looking expression involving $\arcsin$ and $\arctan$. However, you can take advantage of the fact that you’re working with a scaled and translated ellipse for a potentially simpler solution.

The parameterization that you’ve got in your question can be viewed as the unit circle $(\cos\alpha,\sin\alpha)$ scaled, rotated and translated. So, if you undo this transformation, the problem is reduced to finding the intersection of a line with the unit circle. Specifically, the line $x=h$ back-maps to $(R_x\cos\theta)x-(R_y\sin\theta)y+C_x=h$, while the line $y=k$ back-maps to $(R_x\sin\theta)x+(R_y\cos\theta)y+C_y=k$.

Comment: thanks @amd, that trick with transformation is great :D

Comment: For sake of finding my mistakes:
I've tried to solve it with $Acos\alpha - Bsin\alpha = C$ before and it gives me no result, or a single result, but there's two results also possible, so I wonder where I got wrong. I've tried it as follows:
$$A=R_xcos\alpha \\ B=R_ysin\alpha \\ C=x(\alpha)-C_x$$
so knowing that $A cos\alpha - B sin\alpha\equiv Rsin(\alpha-\gamma)$ thing I've got $\alpha=arcsin(\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}})+arctan\frac{B}{A}$ but I've stuck here.

Comment: @tak_se_paczam You have to consider both solutions of $R^2=A^2+B^2$. Also, I believe that you meant to write $A=R_x\cos\theta$ and $B=R_y\sin\theta$ in your comment.

Comment: thanks for your help :)