# What's the parametric function for a rotated ellipse about one of its foci?

Tags: conic-sections

I implemented a code for generating rotated ellipses following the formula given in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645689/what-is-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-ellipse-given-the-angle-of-rotatio) and while it works just fine, I want the ellipse to rotate around one of the **foci**, not around it's centre. I don't know the parametric formula for this effect. I have the effect going in a [Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/r3ju4uc7qi?lang=es).
I've looked already to some of the answers related to this question, but I can't find the right solution.

My solution so far is:

```
x = a*cos(ang)*cos(r) - b*sin(ang)*sin(r) + c
y = a*cos(ang)*sin(r) + b*sin(ang)*cos(r) + c
```

where **a** is the semi-major axis, **b** is the semi-minor axis, **c** = sqrt(a^2-b^2), **ang** is an angle in radians (from 0 to 3600, to get more points into the shape) and **r** is the angle of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha $ is rotation angle around the focus situated at origin, the standard polar Newton form is easily modified:

Single radius vector

$$ \dfrac{1}{r}= \dfrac{1- e \cos (\theta- \alpha) }{p}$$

when parameterized to Cartesian:

$$ (x,y)= r (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$$

[image]