# Curve traced by one vertex of a unit equilateral triangle while the other two vertices slide along the $x$ and $y$ axes

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, parametric

The image below depicts the situation.  An unit equilateral triangle has two of its vertices sliding along the $x$ and $y$ axes, as shown.  What is the curve traced by the third vertex?  If it is an ellipse, what is its equation?

**My attempt:**

If we take $t$ to be the angle between the base of the triangle and the $x$ axis, we can express the coordinates of the third vertex as a function of $t$.

And then, we have to convert the parametric equations of the coordinates of the vertex into the equation of an ellipse.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v_x(t)$ denote the position of the vertex on the $x$-axis at time $t$, $v_y(t)$ denote the position of the vertex on the $y$-axis at time $t$, and $v(t)$ denote the position of the third vertex at time $t$.

First, note that
$$ v_x(t)^2 + v_y(t)^2 = 1, $$
as this is the length of the side of triangle between these two points.  An entirely reasonable parameterization of these two vertices is, then
$$ v_x(t) = (\cos(t), 0)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
v_y(t) = (0, \sin(t)). $$
The third vertex can be found by starting at the midpoint of this segment, and traveling $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ units in a direction perpendicular to the segment.  Abusing notation a little,
$$ v(t)
= \underbrace{\frac{1}{2} (\sin(t), \cos(t))}_{P} + \underbrace{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \langle \cos(t), \sin(t) \rangle}_{\mathbf{v}}
= \left( \frac{1}{2} \sin(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(t), \frac{1}{2} \cos(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin(t) \right). $$
Here, the notation $P + \mathbf{v}$ denotes the addition of a point and vector—start at the point, and travel along the vector to arrive at a new point.  That being said, the addition actually works "componentwise" so, hopefully, nothing too difficult is happening here.

The vector $\mathbf{v}$ does, perhaps, require a little bit of explanation.  The vector from $v_x(t)$ to $v_y(t)$ is
$$ \mathbf{u}(t) = v_y(t) - v_x(t) = \langle -\sin(t), \cos(t) \rangle. $$
A vector perpendicular to this is obtained by swapping the entries, and changing the sign of one of the two entries (the choice of *which* entry's sign is changed comes down to orientation—in the original image, the third vertex sits above the $x$-axis when $t=0$, hence the choice of $\mathbf{v}(t) = \langle \cos(t), \sin(t)\rangle$).

I sketched all of the above up in GeoGebra, and obtained the following image (note that the naming of the vertices is different, as GeoGebra has its own conventions):

[image]

The complete GeoGebra demonstration can be found at https://www.geogebra.org/calculator/jtehwfh7 .

The moral of the story is that the curve can be parameterized by the function
$$ v(t) = \left( \frac{1}{2} \sin(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(t), \frac{1}{2} \cos(t) + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \sin(t) \right), $$
where $t$ runs over the real numbers (though $v$ is $2\pi$-periodic, so it is only necessary to parameterize over, say, $[0,2\pi]$).

I claim that this is a parameterization of an ellipse.  However, instead of reinventing the wheel, I will refer the interested reader to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2647450/ , where a generalized parameterization of an ellipse is derived.  One can work backward from the linked answer to the formula in the question.